# How to retrieve values from DB using ajax in CI

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using CI.2.2. I have developed a like/dislike system like Facebook, and can update the values into the DB success fully. My problem is I cant show the count of likes and dislikes. How can I get rid of this.

View page

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".voteMe").click(function() {
var voteId = this.id;
var upOrDown = voteId.split('_'); 
$.ajax({
type: "post",
url: '<?php echo base_url('family/voteme');?>',
cache: false,    
data:'voteId='+upOrDown[0] + '&upOrDown=' +upOrDown[1],
success: function(response){    
try{
if(response=='true'){ 
alert(success);
var newValue = parseInt($("#"+voteId+'_result').text()) + 1; 
$("#"+voteId+'_result').html(newValue);
}else{alert('Sorry Unable to update..');
}
}catch(e) {  
alert('Exception while request..');
}  
},
error: function(){      
alert('Error while request..');
}
 });
});
});
</script>
```

```html
<div>
<label>
<a class="voteMe" id="<?php echo $pts['familypost_id'];?>_upvote">
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
</a>
<span id="<?php echo $pts['familypost_id'];?>_upvote_result" ></span>
</label>
<label>
<a class="voteMe" id="<?php echo $pts['familypost_id'];?>_downvote">
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>
</a>
<span id="<?php echo $pts['familypost_id'];?>_downvote_result" ></span>
</label>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function voteme()
{
    $voteId=  $this->input->post('voteId');
    $upOrDown=  $this->input->post('upOrDown');

    $status ="false";
    $updateRecords = 0;

    if($upOrDown=='upvote'){
        $updateRecords = $this->family_model->updateUpVote($voteId);
    }else{
        $data['down_votes'] = $this->family_model->updateDownVote($voteId);
    }

    if($updateRecords>0){
        $status = "true";
    }
    echo $status;
}
```

Model:

```
function updateDownVote($voteId){
    $sql = "UPDATE posts set downvotes = downvotes+1 WHERE post_id=?";
    $this->db->query($sql, array($voteId));
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }

    function updateUpVote($voteId){
    $sql = "UPDATE posts set upvotes = upvotes+1 WHERE post_id=?";
    $this->db->query($sql, array($voteId));
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }
```

Problem is updation can be done perfectly. but i don't know why the like and dislike count cant be displayed.

Pl help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

debug ajax scripting on console and check ajax is working proper or not and then alert the result from ajax and if alert is coming properly then check how you handle that result.

I have doubt on this line.

url: '', as url is use two time single quotes and my thought that first will be double quotes ant then single.

Comment: there is no issue in the usage of base_url. its the method which is used by CI to load the base path.

Comment: debug and find what is exat url of ajax and then run it on browser to check the result of that ajax url.